# What is the equivalent of the Django {% block %} and {% extends %} tags in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js

I am modernizing the code of my Django web application by re-creating its frontend in a separate Next.js application. I am having problems finding the equivalent of the Django `{% block %}` tag in Next.js.

Concretely, all pages across my app share the following HTML skeleton: a navbar at the top, and a mainbar and a sidebar below it.

In Django, I achieved this using a **base.html** file containing the navbar, a `{% block mainbar %}` tag, and `{% block sidebar %}` tag and then extended this template from other child templates using {% extends "base.html %}. Here is my Django **base.html**:

```
<body>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <header id="navbar">
        ...
    </header>

    <!-- Body -->
    <div id="body">

        <!-- Mainbar -->
        <main id="mainbar">
            {% block mainbar %}
            {% endblock %}
        </main>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <aside id="sidebar">
            {% block sidebar %}
            {% endblock %}
        </aside>

    </div>

</body>
```

How can I recreate the concept of a `{% block %}` and `{% extends %}` tags in Next.js? Or, how can I recreate a template inheritance structure similar to the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned,

> re-creating its frontend in a separate Next.js application

I assumed you tried to combine Django framework for the backend and using Next.js for the frontend?

You are able to do this, if you use Django as a web services.
Means that your Django will serve data to its frontend using API.

---

And for your question, importing component in NextJS is very easy.

```
import Mainbar from '../components/mainbar'
import Sidebar from '../components/sidebar'

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div id="body">
      <Mainbar />
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  )
}
```

For the complete example, you can refer [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux)